# Can I use solvent based paint on waterborne primer?

Tags: paint, primer

I have some solvent based paint left (Sikkens Rubbol AZ), but the wood panel I want to paint with had been prepared with a waterborne primer (Sikkens Rubbol Primer BL). It doesn't have to last forever, and it's only for indoor use.

Are there any issues with using a solvent based paint on a waterborne primer?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be. Do you have a piece of wood you can test it on.

Comment: Paint is fine, if it is a solid based stain, usually exterior, then no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem.  I have used any cheap water based paint as a primer.  Primer has two functions.  Seal the surface so you use less of the high price spread, and give tooth to the surface for the finish coat to stick.  You don't have to keep it all waterbase or all oil base, unless the paint can directions are specific.